# numeric stability of map reduce operations

Tags: functional-programming, floating-point, numerical-algorithms, mapreduce

I am building a small library for computing information retrieval metrics for classifiers (precision, recall, f1, [accuracy](https://github.com/Boteval/nlu-eval/blob/975f02f34fb94b4ba418d8240fc3fd6ea4826335/src/clojure/org/boteval/nlueval/evaluators/accuracy.clj#L12-L67), whatever). Typically each metric is built by calculating a single value for each object being classified (each metric will have its own formula there) and then calculating a single value (an average) aggregating all those single values; hence a mapper and a reducer.

With little formal training in numeric stability, I wonder what would be the most numerically stable way to calculate the average, and what might be the most interesting trade-offs between stability, avoidance of overflow, and computational complexity (performance).

Also any reference to a mathematical reading in this vein would be entirely welcome, for this, as well as for as similar future cases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way, the language I wrote this in (clojure), directly supports [a numeric type of rational numbers](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/01_primitive-data/1-14_working-with-rational-numbers.asciidoc), which makes an interesting deviation from many standard languages/libraries I know of, and may imply a specialized solution for this question.

Comment: Did you try Googling for "numerically stable average". The first non-SE answer will tell you about [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) (which is the tricky bit of calculating the average).